# AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'below'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find the relative element to the login button on the discord.com/login page, i am trying to locate the register button/element by using the below function i saw on the selenium documentation. I am trying to click it

````
from pydoc import locate
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By



driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:/Users/sexyv/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://discord.com/login")
email_box = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="email")
password_box = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="password")
submit_button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//button[@type='submit']").below(password_box)
def login(driver, email_box, password_box, submit_button):
    email_box.send_keys("johnsonkalel15@gmail.com") 
    password_box.send_keys("Kalel12346")
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    submit_button.click()
    


login(driver=driver,email_box=email_box, password_box=password_box, submit_button=submit_button)```
````

Comment: If you want to click on the register button, then you might do it as 

//*[text()='Register']

Comment: .below(password_box) Just remove this and it'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Below isn't a selenium function

Besides there is only one submit button on the page

The xpath works without the below portion

```
//submit_button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//button[@type='submit']")
```

Comment: i am trying to click the "register" element not the login button